# How to webscrape to items out of table (with python and beautifulsoup)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to webscrape this webpage (caranddriver.com). Therefore, I want to get the trim lines  and prices out of a table.

As I just started coding I would higly appreciate your input! Thanks in advance!! :)

Desired output:

```
SE, $42,000 
SEL, $48,000 
Limited, $53,000
```

Code as of now:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#Inputs/URLs to scrape: 
URL = ('https://www.caranddriver.com/hyundai/ioniq-5')
(response := requests.get(URL)).raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
overview = soup.find()

for a in soup.find('g', class_='trims').find_all('foreignObject'):   
    trim = a.find('span', class_='css-afhlgr e1pdf2xh2').text
    msrp_trim = a.find('span', class_='css-4f1oub e1pdf2xh1').text
    print(trim, msrp_trim)
```

Comment: If you are legitimately "grabbing" this data, and have their permission, I would suggest contacting Car and Driver and asking for access to the data via API or data dump .. Web scraping not only will most likely get you blocked at least temporarily from their DOS protection, but it's considered intellectual theft to straight up "copy" their data, even if it is publicly available (if done without some sort of permission / agreement on the data usage). Furthermore website designs change .. That will eventually render your "scraper" null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.caranddriver.com/hyundai/ioniq-5"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

data = iter(soup.select("foreignObject span"))
for trim, msrp_trim in zip(data, data):
    print("{:<10} {}".format(trim.text, msrp_trim.text))
```

Prints:

```
SE         $42,000 (est)
SEL        $48,000 (est)
Limited    $53,000 (est)
```